# Rulers of Rome - Caesar and Pompei

Tags: ancient-rome

Why is Pompei Magnus' name not lauded as much as Caesar's is as a Roman ruler ,considering Magnus was the one who ran Rome in the first place ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pompey never attained the supreme power that Caesar (briefly, before he was murdered, did). Although he at times (such as when he was fighting the pirates or when he was consul *sine collegio* in the late 50s BCE) had great *imperium*, he was always either reluctant or unable to arrogate to himself the **fount** of this power. Therefore, he was always either a member of a power-sharing arrangement or the champion of the conservative/reactionary party. So he can't be really counted as a ruler.

Having said that, I must say that some scholars do espouse the view that you suggested - that Pompey can be viewed as the first *princeps*. Not being a professional, I don't have a ready reference for that right now, but some googling led me to a [corroboration](http://chrestomathy.cofc.edu/documents/vol9/SWilliams.pdf) of this statement (p. 240 there):

> Pompey the Great, considered by some to be the first princeps, had
>   unmatched influence in Rome, which conflicted with the Republican
>   system that restricted such a consolidation of influence (Beard and
>   Crawford 85).

EDIT: I found it! The great [Syme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Syme) himself penned the memorable [suggestion](http://books.google.ie/books?id=zlp5orrpC4gC&pg=PR11&lpg=PR11&dq=syme%20%22pompey%20won%22&source=bl&ots=ss793Zn4OO&sig=KlhdCw5LmlTxmONZFbuhBtn5_ZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kygpUfjZBMS1hAfYj4GwDQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=syme%20%22pompey%20won%22&f=false) that had Pompey won he would have been killed at the foot of his own statue by honourable men.

Comment: You'd probably have to give the palm of first emperor to Sulla, not Pompey.

Comment: [If Sulla could, why can't I?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulla#Legacy)